# Combining ratios in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is more of a math problem, but I was wondering how to sum a ratio so that the value is still accurate. I have a dataframe of suicide stats for every country that looks like:

```
   per100k continent  year     country
   6.71    Europe  1987     Albania     
   5.0     Europe  1987     Germany
```

I'm going to group this dataframe by continent and was wondering the best way to "sum" the per100K (number of suicides per 100k residents) to preserve this ratio. I could recalculate this value since I have access to the raw number of residents and the total number of suicides, but I would rather do this using the pandas groupby function. I've looked through the list of functions on the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) method but none of them seem to fit my use case.

Answer (score 1):

I refer to this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/why-is-an-average-of-an-average-usually-incorrect/95912) for reference about why "the average of the average" is the WRONG approach for this.

If you have data, better to sum the populations and events and divide those.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'continent':['europe', 'europe', 'america', 'america'], 'year':[1987, 1987, 1987, 1987], 'country': ['albania','germany', 'canada', 'mexico'], 'population': [50, 100, 60, 70], 'events':[8, 10, 7, 4]
})

df['ratio'] = df.events / df.population

ratio_BAD = df.groupby('continent')['ratio'].mean().reset_index()
```

This would output:

```
continent   ratio
0   america 0.086905
1   europe  0.130000
```

Now, alternatively lets sum the values and divide:

```
continents = df.groupby('continent')[['population', 'events']].sum().reset_index()

continents['ratio_GOOD'] = population.events / population.population

continent   

            population  events  ratio_GOOD
0   america     130     11      0.073333
1   europe      150     18      0.120000
```

So, values are different and you'd prefer this last approach.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I'd have to do something like that, but wanted to make sure there wasn't a built-in function to make these kinds of operations easier.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be a meaningful data if there is not another weight point such as population etc. If you can add the other counts like total suicides and population beside of the ratio, you can give a weight. You can check this :

https://pbpython.com/weighted-average.html